# How to IAB with multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

this one is bogging me how to implement and cant really find anything good on stackoverflow.

The question is, how to do you use IABHelper with multiple activities, when each activity can also make purchases, not only use invetory state

Of course all the examples have it in MainActivity and thats it. What if I need to make purchase from my DetailActivity? I cant just ask for data of some IabHelperManager singleton which is init ed by MainActivity because of process killing and MainActivity will not be revived until in foreground if DetailActivity was in foreground before killing etc etc.. Application object would be good but IabHelper is very tied to Activity with onActivityResult and has dispose method which is weird in app. obj. as it has none?

So .. what do you guys do , just have IabHelper instance per Activity? This seems the only way to do it 100% correctly for me, but seems kinda wasteful to ask for inventory every time user enters DetailActivity which is going to be often..

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have the same issue.

Comment: yea, just have singleton with latch counts, and only really init / deinit if the count is 0